# "Invalid command bdist_wheel" in Ubuntu 16.04 when building from TF source

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I currently am trying to build from Tensorflow 1.5 source because I am trying to implement a model on mobile and had to include some kernels. I have run through .configure in TF and I'm pointing at the 3.5 python location.

I am now trying to build the wheel file and for the life of me cannot get around the invalid command bdist_wheel error.  I am currently at the step of building the wheel file using:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
```

And I receive the following error:

> Thu Feb 22 11:17:38 PST 2018 : === Using tmpdir: /tmp/tmp.XPe7Djtgg2
>   ~/Documents/Git/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package.runfiles
>   ~/Documents/Git/tensorflow ~/Documents/Git/tensorflow
>   /tmp/tmp.XPe7Djtgg2 ~/Documents/Git/tensorflow Thu Feb 22 11:17:39 PST
>   2018 : === Building wheel usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1
>   [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]    or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2
>   ...]    or: setup.py --help-commands    or: setup.py cmd --help
>
> error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

I have also tried making sure wheel is installed but when I type:

> sudo pip3 install wheel

I receive the following message.

> Requirement already satisfied: wheel in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages

I went into my .bashrc file and have an entry for
**export PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/**

Now looking in build_pip_package I saw that it is using the line below to trigger the wheel build:

```
"${PYTHON_BIN_PATH:-python}" setup.py bdist_wheel ${PKG_NAME_FLAG} >/dev/null
```

At the path /usr/bin/ the symlink for python is for 2.7 which I think is the issue, because when I installed wheel using pip2, the wheel file built but it was for 2.7 and not 3.5 so it stated that it couldnt install the wheel file for the current environment.

I thought that maybe modifying the line above to the below entry would work but I still get the same bdist error.  I cannot figure out how to get the wheel to build under 3.5.

```
"${PYTHON_BIN_PATH:-python3.5}" setup.py bdist_wheel ${PKG_NAME_FLAG} >/dev/null
```

I also tried setting an alias for python to python3.5 which works fine when I try to call just python at the command prompt but it does not work when it is being called from within the "build_pip_package" wheel building call.

Anyone know how I might be able to resolve this?  I assume if I were to install conda I can probably get around this, but I would prefer not to have to deal with that if at all possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found what my issue was in this specific case. I initially performed the Tensorflow configure and wasn't aware of PYTHON_BIN_PATH at the time.  now from reading, it seems that when I ran configure, it should have created this entry (at least from what I understand). This did not happen and it was only when I was dealing with the error stated above that I dug deeper and found that build_pip_package was accessing that variable and that it was not set in my .bashrc.  It was at this time that I added the value and was trying to just run the building of the wheel.

After posting here, I then figured I would try rerunning through the full TF building process again and see if I could spot any other errors that I might have missed along the way.  It was here that I then got an error stating that **/usr/bin/** was a path which just happened to be the same value assigned to **PYTHON_BIN_PATH**.  I modified it to export PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python3 and then rebuilt tensorflow and once I finished I continued with building the wheel and installing it and all went through correctly.

Hopefully this helps someone at one point.